# where do we declare the notification center object

Tags: ios, swift4

It would be good if anybody could explain me properly about the notification center, the declaration and usage of the same in swift

```
let nc = NotificationCenter.default
nc.post(name: Notification.Name("UserLoggedIn"), object:nil)
```

where do we declare this??

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have 2 `ViewController`

1. FeedListController
2. CreateFeedController

Now the scenario is that when you create new Fees Post from `CreateFeedController` then newly created feed refreshed in `FeedListController`. for that you can use `NotificationCenter`.

You can also use this as per your recruitment.

so for that you need to `addObserver` in that `Viewcontroller` in which you want to perform some action when something happen so you can add observer like below in your `FeedListController`.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(refreshFeedList), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refreshFeedList"), object: nil)
```

**Method in `FeedListController` which get new data from API**

```
@objc func refreshFeedList() {
    // Call Your APO to get New Data
}
```

You need to post that like below from `CreateFeedController` once you create new Feed.

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("refreshFeedList"), object: nil)
```

Once this fire it will call `FeedListController` `refreshFeedList` and new data automatically loads.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned code will go from where you want a notification to be broadcasted.

Add an observer to the class where you want to perform anything depending on that notification

**Example**

**Receiver:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addObservers()
    }

    deinit {
        removeObservers()
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForegroundNotification(_ notification: Notification) {

    }


    fileprivate func addObservers() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.applicationWillEnterForegroundNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
    }

    fileprivate func removeObservers() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name:  NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
    }

}
```

**Broadcaster:**

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
```